# Why doesn't the URL constructor encode brackets in query strings?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, the `URL` constructor does not encode brackets and parentheses when they are in a query string where as `encodeURI` or `encodeURIComponent` always encodes them. This confuses me because most sources say to encode your query params when they contain special characters using `encodeURI`/`encodeURIComponent`. I would expect the `URL` object to have similar behavior.

This causes me problems writing unit tests since I do not know how the query params from the URL object will be encoded. Is there a spec for this or should I always just encode my params before using `URL` constructor? Thank you for your help.

---

example showing URL object not encoding brackets in query string

```js
const href = (new URL('https://foobar.com?myQuery={"@asdf/asdf":"1234"}')).href;
//     ^ https://foobar.com/?myQuery={%22@asdf/asdf%22:%221234%22}
```

if I use `encodeURI`, the only difference is the brackets are encoded

```js
const href = encodeURI('https://foobar.com?myQuery={"@asdf/asdf":"1234"}');
//     ^ https://foobar.com?myQuery=%7B%22@asdf/asdf%22:%221234%22%7D
```

---

NOTE: The URL object *does* encode brackets if they are not in a query param.

```js
const href = (new URL('https://foobar.com/}}}?myQuery={"@asdf/asdf":"1234"}')).href;
//     ^ https://foobar.com/%7D%7D%7D?myQuery={%22@asdf/asdf%22:%221234%22}
```

Comment: Different components of a URL have different character restrictions. The `URL` code takes this into account when deciding what needs to be encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple encodings possible that all should be interpreted a the same url, so none are technically wrong. Another example is that percent encoding can be done with uppercase or lowercase characters (`%aa` or `%AA`), and the domain is case-insensitive and spaces may be encoded (in some parts) as either `+` or `%20`.

if you want to unittest a specific URL encoder implmententation you can match strings, but if you want to know if 2 urls are identical *regardless* of how it was encoded you first need to go through step called 'normalization' before comparison.